# Is Android Support Reposity includeable in Eclipse Neon?

Tags: android, eclipse

for certain compatibility reasons, I have to use Eclipse Neon for Android Development to develop an android app. Therefore I also have to use the newest Android SDK so I can implement some newest features.

Now, I am facing the problem that I cannot compile any Android app with Eclipse, because I get errors like

The import android.support cannot be resolved
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name "ThemeAppCompat. …"

upon building. As I found out, this is because Eclipse is missing the "Android support library" (android support library.jar ?) in the sdk folder. The reason for this is, as I found out, that this library is obsolete and has been replaced by the "Android support repository". It has not been installed by the Android SDK manager and cannot be installed anymore, but Eclipse still needs it apparently.

I searched a lot for a solution for this but all answers I could find was "Swtich to Android Studio"… Unfortunately, there is no way around using Eclipse for me. Is there any known way to include the support repository and make eclipse use it? I found this site

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

and thought, maybe I can follow these steps to make my app to a gradle.build and then include the stuff from the repository and get my stuff to work, but unfortunately I could not find a way to realize this.

I changed the related section in the gradle.build file to this:

…

dependencies {

…
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

}

…

but could not get the app being built.

Is there any known solution for this? I actually cannot imagine that I am the only one trying to develop an Android App with the new support repository file these days. Should I maybe manually insert the obsolete (but newest) android support library.jar file from an older IDE? Could this work?

Thank you many times for your help.

Comment: The support libraries still exist in the SDK Manager. Eclipse never did it include the support libraries, it was always externally managed by the Androd SDK home directory

Comment: of course they are still there, but not the way as they were in the past. They are inside the folder m2repository now and have different formats (not .jar but .aar, .md5, .sha1, .pom, ....) and Eclipse is apparently not compatible with that.

Comment: I dont know the backgrounds in detail, maybe it has something to do with that Android SDK home directory... but for me it clearly looks like a compatibility issue. What can I do now?

Comment: Eclipse should simply use Gradle to pull the necessary dependencies. And you don't need Eclipse to compile the app. Gradle can be ran from command line. If all else fails, there's plenty of resources for how to configure Android Studio to run on low end machines

Comment: Okay I somehow succeeded in making the project to a gradle one. At least, there is a build.gradle file in the project folder. Can you explain me in detail, how I have to set that dependency exactly and how I can compile that project (simple hello world app right now)?

Comment: The Android SDK manager installs the Google Support Repository locally on your computer. Unfortunately, a recent update to the Android SDK made that  Manager entirely command line based without Android Studio, and I've not figured out how it works. https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager